# Sharing data between users - without a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET (4.0) webforms application and I would like to know what options I have when it comes to sharing data between users in my web application.

The most obvious solution would be a database table. But are there any alternatives? I've read something about "Application scope", but I'm not sure that it'll be useful for this scenario.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database?  By the sound of it it's exactly what you should be using.

Comment: @Servy The database currently has ~300 tables so I would like to solve it in another way - if possible.

Comment: If the application has a high level of complexity it's all the more reason this information belongs in one, as opposed to pretty much any other option.  The only reason I'd consider anything else for this would be if this is a hello world application and you couldn't be bothered to learn how to configure a database, but that's clearly not the case here.  Sounds like you simply need to spend some time structuring your database appropriately, perhaps using schemas or even multiple database instances to segregate (and thus modularize) the data to make it easier to work with.

Comment: @Servy I don't have any problems with the database structure. I was just curious if there was any other options available. But thanks for the info, guess I'll stick to my database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications is what you are searching for.

```
if (Application["CurrentUsers"] == null)
    Application["CurrentUsers"] = 0;
Application["CurrentUsers"] += 1;
```

Just an example for an current online counter.

To react to the lifetime, see the `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["CurrentUsers"] = 0;
}
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["CurrentUsers"] = null;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but for how long will the application object live?

Comment: As long as your app is alive. So, whenever **all** Sessions get abandoned, the Applications are lost too. For example, if you restart your IIS.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell Ok, thanks. Another case would be if all users leave my site I suppose?

Comment: @Johan, no, but after some time the worker will shut down. You can control this via your IIS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Application object  Or store it in a in-memory database

Comment: Is the application object automatically cleared at some point?

Comment: till the worker process not recycled or you need to clear it.

Comment: This happens when the app pool get recycled or when the app restarted on IIS. It also happens when the web.config get changed. You can hook to the application events with Application_Start and Application_End in the global.asax

Comment: Giorgio's comment about app pool recycling is an important one to note - even a healthy web server has the app pool recycled normally when it's idle, or every 29 hours (I think it's 29...). So even if you're running normally, you can still lose everything on a regular basis.